# App works on Emulator but not on real Phone, Add and Remove View

Tags: android, canvas, view, draw

I am just drawing a Circle with canvas, and change the radius with a SeekBar. This Code works fine on Emulator, but on my phone the remove View thing doesn't work. Means the circle gets bigger and bigger, but not smaller on my phone.

What is the problem here ?

my Code:

```
public class Kreis extends Activity  implements OnSeekBarChangeListener    {
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    public static int radius = 30;
    private TextView textview;
    private static View alterKreis;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kreis);
        this.seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.radiusbar);
        this.textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ausgabe);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);



    }


@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    radius = seekbar.getProgress();
    textview.setText(radius + "");
    RelativeLayout lp=new RelativeLayout(this);



    Circle view = new Circle(this);
    lp.removeView(view);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);



    addContentView(view,params);

}



@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class Circle extends View{


        public Circle(Context context) {
            super(context);


        }
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {


            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

       //     if(radius>0){
            canvas.drawCircle(200,200,radius,paint);
        //    }

        }


    }
```

}

Comment: What's the API level on your phone? and on your emulator?

Comment: Oh thank you, i picked a too high API Level at my AndroidManifest.xml. I thought this wouldnt matter, cause i have Android 4.0 on my phone. But it did. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the errors are so small and hide so well, that we don't even notice them at a first sight.